# HTML form for text and file uploads

Tags: html, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I have a simple html form that I want to use in order to send text and files to my server. I've followed the answers on similar questions and I've added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to my form.

My form is:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="create" action="/person" method="post" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" required>
        </li>
    </ul>       
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="picture">Picture</label>
            <input type="file" name="picture" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and my Controller (Spring Boot) expects the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@RequestParam String name,
                       @RequestParam MultipartFile picture)
    {...}
```

I'm getting the following result (when submitting a complete form with all of the required fields filled and a file selected to be uploaded):

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required String parameter 'name' is not present
```

Removing the file-related stuff from the form and the Controller give me the expected results and the text information is sent as expected.

Any ideas? Am I missing something obvious in this code?

Comment: could you add an exit('Yep'); on the top the the controller function? Just to be test/sure it goes to the controller at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="create" action="/person" method="post" >
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="" required="required" id="name"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="picture">Picture</label>
                <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```

And controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/person", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void create(@RequestParam(name = "name") String name,
                       @RequestParam(name = "picture") MultipartFile picture)
```

Comment: Didn't work...
I added ids for all of my form's fields and I also added

@RequestParam(required=false,name="name")  String name,

in my Controller.

I can now hit breakpoins in my controller but all values come as null

Comment: I tried this codes in my project and it worked well.